# How to use SignalR in React Native?

Tags: react-native, signalr

How do I implement SignalR in react native for implementing push notifications?

I have seen implementing SiganlR in react js by using packages like https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR.

I didn't find any solution for implementing signalR in React Native

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr

Comment: @Reza is this package well maintained?

Comment: @SibinFawaz no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package. I am using it right now, it works fine but i have a problem with reconnect hub.start(). 
You can install with this :

```
npm install @aspnet/signalr
```

Example:

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chat")
    .build();

connection.on("send", data => {
    console.log(data);
});

connection.start()
    .then(() => connection.invoke("send", "Hello"));
```

Comment: Please sum up all infos directly here on SO. So you make sure even if the project is gone, all stilll know how to do this.